# Scope value not updating in view in IONIC 1 and Angular js

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework, scope

I have a requirement like saving two previous login details.
I am done with it. But my view will update only on refresh.But scope values are updated.

Tried with `scope.apply`,`digest`,`timeout`. But nothing seems to work here.

```
$scope.loginUserName=localStorage.getItem("loginUserName");

$scope.userName=localStorage.getItem("userName");
$scope.mobileNumber=localStorage.getItem("mobileNumber");


$scope.loginData = {};

$scope.userLogin = function(loginData) {
userService.userLogin(loginData).then(function(success) {
  var res=success.message;
  if(res==='success'){
    if(localStorage.getItem("userName1")==null || localStorage.getItem("userName1") == success.firstName){
    localStorage.setItem("userName1",success.firstName);
    localStorage.setItem("loginUserName",success.firstName);
    }else if(localStorage.getItem("userName2")==null || localStorage.getItem("userName2") == success.firstName ){
    localStorage.setItem("userName2",success.firstName);
    localStorage.setItem("loginUserName",success.firstName);
    }
    localStorage.setItem("userName",success.firstName);
    $scope.userName=success.firstName;
    $scope.mobileNumber = success.mobileNumber;
    $scope.loginData = {};
    $state.go('app.home');
  }else{
    $scope.message ='Wrong pin.Try again or click Forgot password to reset it.';
  }
},function(error){

});
```

};

```
$scope.loginPerson = function(mobileNumber,userName){
localStorage.setItem("loginUserName",userName);
// here userName is updating,but not reflecting in view
$scope.loginUserName=localStorage.getItem("loginUserName");
//setTimeout(function(){ $scope.$apply(); });
console.log("In loginPerson:"+userName);
$state.go('app.start');
```

}

**start.html**

```
 <span ng-if="loginUserName !=null">
      <p class="startP">Enter pin for {{loginUserName}} 
<i class="icon ion-chevron-down" ui-sref="app.loginOptions">
        </i></p>
     </span>
```

**State**

```
  //Here is the state details,I have same controller for two state.

  .state('app.loginOptions', {
  url: '/loginOptions',
  views: {
  'menuContent': {
    templateUrl: 'templates/loginOptions.html',
    controller:'LoginCtrl'
   }
  }
 })

 .state('app.start',{
 url:'/start',
 views:{
  'menuContent':{
    templateUrl:'templates/start.html',
    controller:'LoginCtrl'
   }
 }
```

**EDIT**

I have used within object also,But nothing is changed.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `loginUserName` as a property of an object instead a property of scope directly. Sometimes angularjs fail to update view  for these values.

**Like**

```
$scope.data={
 loginUserName:""
};
```

**Then inside your function**

```
$scope.userLogin = function(loginData) {
 ...

 $scope.data.loginUserName=localStorage.getItem("loginUserNa‌​me");
// To check it
console.log($scope.data);

}
```

**html**

```
 <span ng-if="data.loginUserName !=null">
  ...
     </span>
```

#### Update

**Change the loginPerson function like below.**

```
$scope.loginPerson = function(mobileNumber,userName){
  localStorage.setItem("loginUserName",userName);

$scope.data.loginUserName=localStorage.getItem("loginUserName");

console.log("In loginPerson:"+userName);
console.log($scope.data);

}
```

Comment: `$scope.login={};
   $scope.login.loginUserName=localStorage.getItem("loginUserName");`

Comment: As before in controller its working,But in view am getting empty object

Comment: Actually in code which i pasted. View will reflect on page refresh. I want without refresh

Comment: @Hema When is this `loginUserName` get update ? when calling `$scope.loginPerson` function .Is it triggered by button click.

Comment: Yes.. It will trigger by ng-click

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163247/discussion-between-hema-and-sachin).

Answer (score 0):

step 1) please use angular copy while get data from localstorage to $scope `$scope.xyz=angular.copy(localstorage.get('key'))`

after implement step 1 then not work use `$scope.$apply();` after set value in $scope.

Comment: Thank you for ur response.. `Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress`

Comment: If `Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress`. Then try wrapping that in $timeout().